# Observe changes in an object property with Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular2 application I have an object with some properties similar to this:

```
var person = { 
   firstname:"Tom", 
   lastname:"Hanks" 
};
```

If one of these properties, for example "firstname" changes to "Bill", I would like to hide some elements in the HTML page.
Is there any way to observe the changes of this object? What is the best way to do this using RxJS? I am a novice to Angular and RxJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Wrap the object in a multicast observable like [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject).

Controller

```js
const personSrc = new BehaviorSubject<any>({ 
  firstname:"Tom", 
  lastname:"Hanks" 
};

const person$ = this.personSrc.asObservable();
```

2. Display it in the template using the `async` pipe.

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(person$ | async) as person">
  <span *ngIf="person['firstname'] !== 'Bill'">
    {{ person.lastname }}
    Some properties
  <span>
</ng-container>
```

3. Push any changes to the object through the observable.

Controller

```js
this.personSrc.next({firstname: "Bill", lastname: "Watterson"})
```

Answer (score 2):

you can Observe object property by `distinctUntilKeyChanged`

> `distinctUntilKeyChanged` - Only emit when the specified key value has
> changed

Example:

```
console.clear();
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { distinctUntilKeyChanged } from "rxjs/operators";

const personSrc = new BehaviorSubject<any>({
  firstname: "Tom",
  lastname: "Hanks"
});

setTimeout(() => {
  const newPerson = { firstname: "Bill", lastname: "Smith" };
  personSrc.next(newPerson);
}, 5000);

personSrc.pipe(distinctUntilKeyChanged("firstname")).subscribe(console.log);
```

When the value of `firstname` is changed it will emit a new value

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-distinct-example-a7t4jk?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can use subjects.

```
export class YourService {
  person$: Subject<Person> = new Subject<Person>();

  setPerson(person) {
    this.person$.emit(person);
  };
}
```

your component:

```
constructor(
  private yourService: YourService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
 
  this.yourService.person$.subscribe(person => {
    // here you get the new data
 });
}

changePersonName() {
   this.person.firstName = 'Bill';
   this.yourService.setPerson(this.person); // this will fire the person$ Subject
}
```