# Is there a way to subscribe to part of BehaviorSubject value changes?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let's say I have a behavior subject whose value consists of an object with two properties. Is there a way to subscribe to changes on only one of the properties of the underlying value?

```
export interface MyObject {
  property1: string,
  property2: string
};
const subject = new BehaviorSubject<MyObject>({
  property1: 'test',
  property2: 'test'
});
subject.next({
  property1: 'test',
  property2: 'test2'
});
subject.subscribe(value => {
  // how to only fire for changes on property2?
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Observe changes in an object property with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65699335/observe-changes-in-an-object-property-with-angular)

Comment: This does not answer the question as any changes to the BehaviorSubject would be fired. I think what I need is the distinctUntilChanged operator posted below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [distinctUntilChanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged) operator, and pass in a function which describes what counts as equal. If two successive values are equal, the second one gets filtered out:

```
subject.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.property2 === curr.property2)
).subscribe(value => {
  // do stuff
})
```

Equivalently, you could use [distinctUntilKeyChanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilkeychanged):

```
subject.pipe(
  distinctUntilKeyChanged('property2')
).subscribe(value => {
  // do stuff
})
```

The above examples will still output the entire object. If you only want to output property 2, you could instead map to that, and again use distinctUntilChanged, though you won't need a custom equality function

```
subject.pipe(
  map(value => value.property2),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
).subscribe(property2 => {
  // do stuff
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`distinctUntilKeyChanged`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/distinctUntilKeyChanged) like this:

```js
const source = subject.pipe(
    distinctUntilKeyChanged('property2')
);

source.subscribe();
```

Here `source` will only emit when `property2` has changed since the previous emission.